# Is it safe to use a reinterpret_cast if I can guarantee the correct type was used to allocate the memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, casting

I am trying to make my C++ code cross platform. On Windows I am using the Windows.h header file and on macOS and Linux I use the unistd.h header file.

I am calling a function if the OS is windows which takes a char* type. The equivalent call for mac and linux takes char**. I currently have a function that takes a void* type so that I can have 1 function for both cases. I then check the operating system and reinterpret_cast to the correct type.

```
void DoSomething(void* thing) {

  #if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__)

  // Init thing as char**
  thing = new char*[...];
    thing[0] = new char[...];
    .
    .
    .

  UnixFunction(reinterpret_cast<char**>(thing));

  #elif defined(_WIN32)

  // Init thing as char*
  thing = new char[...];
  WindowsFunction(reinterpret_cast<char*>(thing));
  #endif
}

int main() {

  void* thing;
  DoSomething(thing);

  return 0;

}
```

Regardless if I *should* do this, is this safe or is this undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking about would be safe.  However, your code looks a bit off:

```
void DoSomething(void* thing) {
    thing = new char*[...];
```

That will leave the caller with no access to the allocated memory, because `thing` is an addressed the caller passed in but then you immediately overwrote the address, so you have no way to write into the memory the caller gave you, and/or the caller has no way to know what memory you allocated.

You could take `(void*& thing)` so that your changes to the pointer are visible to the caller, for example.  Or just return the pointer from the function instead.

If you fix that design error, `reinterpret_cast` won't itself be a problem.  You can even cast pointers to `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` and back again using `reinterpret_cast` if you want a way to just pass addresses around without needing to know the type until you use them again.